# AngularJS - Trigger angular app to reload data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an app that gets JSON data from my backend service on page load. That works fine. My existing framework that I have allows each component (DIV) to be refreshed to get the latest data through a javascript function.

```
<div class="breakdownChart" ng-app="breakdown" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="breakdownSummaryRow in breakdownResults.summary.rows" >
        <div class="breakdownChartRow" >
            <div class="breakdownChartValue">{{breakdownSummaryRow.positiveDuration}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var breakdownApp = angular.module('breakdown', []);

function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    jsonDataUrl = "${jsonDataUrl}";
    scope = $scope;
    $scope.fetchData = function () {
        var httpRequest = $http.get('http://localhost:8080' + jsonDataUrl).success(function (data) {
            $scope.breakdownResults = data.data;
        });
    };
}

function load(extraParams) {}
```

I want the load function to trigger the angular app to recall the $http.get call and update the app with the latest data. The problem I am having is I dont have the $scope or $http context to pass to the PhoneListCtrl function. I am thinking that I should be telling the app to refresh and that will call the PhoneListCtrl function?

Can you help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to reload all or only the data for one controller? How would this be triggered? User clicks button? Would `<button ng-click="fetchData()">Refresh</button>` what you want?

Comment: An external button outside of angular calls the load() function. (It refreshes many other things on the page too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a button tag inside the `div` marked with `ng-controller`. e.g. After your `ng-repeat` `div` you can create that button.

Give it a `ng-click` with a function that will be defined on the controller javascript. That function can be your `load()` function and that will trigger the data reload. The function needs to be on the controller and the html needs to be inside controller space to work.